# Setting cookies in python request sessions

Tags: python, python-requests, session-cookies

Im learning web scraping and trying to create a script that checks if certain items are available on buff.163.com. To search on this site, you need to be logged in. I have manually injected cookies on a browser and it has logged me in and worked fine. However, I cannot seem to reproduce in python requests.

Current code:

```
cookie_test = {
'session': 'hidden',
'csrf_token':'hidden',
'Locale-Supported':'en',
'game':'csgo',
'Device-Id':'hidden',
}

headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36' }

url = 'https://buff.163.com/goods/43011?from=market#tab=selling&tag_ids=447197&page_num=1&sort_by=paintwear.asc&paintseed=555'

session = requests.session()
session.cookies.update(cookie_test)
session.headers.update(headers)
response = session.get(url)
```

If I call response.cookies, they are not set and printing out the text also confirms this.
Pointing out my silly mistakes would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Are those supposed to be 5 separate cookies, or are they 5 fields in a single cookie?

Comment: @TimRoberts 5 separate cookies